# Is it possible to get a match back from pexpect.expect?

Tags: python, pexpect

I'm automating testing of a menu that is dynamically generated--that is, each item could get one of several numbers before it. I could say

```
a = child.expect('1\) Set Password', '2\) Set Password', '3\) Set Password')
if a == 0: child.sendline('1')
elif a == 1: child.sendline('2')
elif a == 2: child.sendline('3')
```

But that's rather clunky. I'd rather have something like:

```
child.expect('(\d)\) Set Password')
a = child.get_match()
child.sendline(a)
```

Is there any such function?

Comment: `child.match.group(1)` should get you the bit you want.

Comment: I prefer `child.match.group(0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thomas K provide this answer in a comment:

```
 child.match.group(1)
```

should get you the bit you want.

And indeed, it does.